# Moments of a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can I have higher order moments, for example, the skewness of a complex matrix, in terms of the trace and eigenvalues? As in this paper https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(80)90258-X, they established two quantities related to the mean and standard deviation. Theorem 3.1 (see equation 3.10) says

Let **A** be an n x n complex matrix, and let

$m = tr(A)/n$ and $s_a^2 = tr(A^*A)/n - |m|^2$

Then,...

Those scalar quantities seem to be some moments of one complex matrix. How can I express other scalar quantities that represent higher-order moments?

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is Hermitian with eigenvalues $\lambda_i $ consider the probability on $R$ defined by $$P(dx)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\delta_{\lambda_i}(dx).$$

Comment: Ok. But $A$ is complex, not necessarily Hermitian, so can we express some similar quantity related to the skewness?